# vue routing with extra?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource, vue-router

I have this wired problem:

I am using vue-route, so my login link is: `http://localhost/#!/login`

I have a `<form>` to login:

```
<button @click="submit()">Login</button>
```

the submit button will call a login function, it will then use vue-resource to make a API call, it will just stop at $http.post below:

```
context.$http.post(LOGIN_URL, creds).then(function (res) {
```

It will then direct to : `http://localhost/?#!/login` <- an extra ?

This only happen once when login is loaded, sub sequence it work correctly.

---

If I take out the the form, the problem go away:

```
<form class="form">
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're not preventing the default action of the button?

Buttons, when defined in the context of a form, [are automatically assumed to be `submit` buttons](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-button-element).

You can easily fix that by adding a `type="button"` to the button:

```
<button type="button" @click="submit()">Login</button>
```

Comment: Yes, but I won't be able to use enter key to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this problem by preventing the form from refresh :

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent></form>
```